# Changing secondary menu format

Tags: views, theming

Secondary menu links are listed with the default theme.

I want to add a hover option to it so that menu links will always pop up when a user hovers on a button.

I already built it with html but I couldnt integrate the existing codes in it.

html

```
<a class="button white_bg black_f btn-hasdd" href="#">
<div class="sub">
<ul class="white_bg lastcolor_f">
</div>
```

drupal default code

```
    <?php if ($secondary_menu): ?>
      <div id="secondary-menu" class="navigation">
        <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
          'links' => $secondary_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'secondary-menu-links',
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Secondary menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
        )); ?>
      </div> <!-- /#secondary-menu -->
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#header -->

  <?php if ?>
```

FYI: I couldnt locate to `function links__system_secondary_menu` in any of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use CSS to style the links. Looking at your code, the secondary menu has an id `secondary-menu-links`. So target that within your CSS:

```
#secondary-menu-links a:hover {
  /* your pop-out effect here */
}
```